# The integral of $1/u(2-u^2)^{1/2}$ with respect to $u$.

Tags: calculus

$$\int \frac{1}{u(2-u^2)^\frac{1}{2}} \, du$$ where $u ={2^\frac{1}{2}}{\sin \theta}$, $du={2^\frac{1}{2}}{\cos \theta} \, d\theta$

Rewrite as

$$\int \frac{2^\frac{1}{2}\cos \theta}{(2^\frac{1}{2}\sin \theta)(2^\frac{1}{2}\cos \theta)} \, d\theta$$

Cross out to get

$$\frac{1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} \int \csc \theta \, d\theta= -\frac{1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} \ln \lvert \csc \theta + \cot \theta \rvert$$

sub back in to get

$$-\frac{1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} \ln \lvert \frac{2^\frac{1}{2} + (2^\frac{1}{2} + x^2)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} \rvert + C$$

I've no idea where I went wrong, but the online homework assignment is saying I am wrong.
Also, could someone inform me or link me to how I can write this normally? I'm sure it's all very difficult to follow in this format.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not readable.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is information on how to use MathJax and write your expressions properly.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Thank you very much, someone kindly helped me along with the editing, but I'm glad I know how to now.

Comment: Also, don't forget closing parentheses and the "dx" at the end of integrals >:(

Comment: Yeah, I've lost several parts forgetting that on exams >.>

Comment: I'm not understanding the substitution in step two, specifically the $\left(2-u^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$ part. Did you make sure to substitute the $u$ correctly?

Comment: I actually accepted an edit that misrepresented my u value. My u should be $ \sqrt2$sin$\theta$

Answer (score 0):

what about the change of variable $$2 - u^2 = 2t^2, u^2 = 2 - 2t^2, 2u\, du = -4t \,dt $$ so that the 
$$\begin{align}\int \frac{du}{u\sqrt{2-u^2}} &= -\int \frac{2t\, dt/u}{ut\sqrt 2} =-\sqrt 2 \int \frac{ dt}{1-t^2}\\& = -\frac 1{\sqrt 2} \int\left(\frac{1}{1+t} +\frac{1}{1-t}\right)\, dt \\
&= -\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)\\
&= -\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt 2+\sqrt{2-u^2}}{\sqrt 2-\sqrt{2-u^2}}\right)+C\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry if I am being a bit dense, but why exactly does 2-u^2 = 2t^2?

Is this method similar to u-substitution?

Comment: this another way of arriving at the same result as you have. you used a trig substitution and i used an algebraic one. we must arrive at the same/equivalent answer.

Comment: That doesn't really help. I don't understand what I'm doing.

Comment: you can make your life easier if you first sub $u = \sqrt 2 x$